# Javascript clearInterval not working with variable

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

So I am trying to make a type of game. A prompt window appears when user clicks on the start button. The user enters a number between 1 to 9. Three numbers then appear and they change every second. The user gets a point if they click on the number that they selected. When the user clicks on stop, the interval stops.
However in my case, the interval is not stopping at all. Here is a sample of the code

```js
var callback;
var call=window.setInterval(callback,3000);
function Start(){//prompts,does validation and then setsinterval as so 
(function(){
  callback=function(){
  //declares numbers
  };
  callback();
  window.setInterval(callback,3000);
  })();
  }
  function Stop(){
    clearInterval(call);
        }
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="Start()">Start Game</button>
<button type="button" onclick="Stop()">Stop Game</button>
```

Comment: Hmm, based on that code your interval will never _start_, because `callback` doesn't exist when `var call=window.setInterval(callback,3000);` runs, and `start()` will not be executed when the button is clicked, because JS function names are case-sensitive and your function is called `start()` not `Start()`. Since you're complaining that the callback doesn't _stop_, is this just a typo in your example code?

Comment: Also, you seem to be trying to start the interval before the button is clicked, which doesn't match how you've described the situation. And within the start() function, you then set the interval again, but without assigning it to the `call` variable, which I think is the root of the problem you're actually asking about - since the first attempt to set the interval failed, and the second attempt doesn't assign it to the variable, then when `clearInterval()` runs, `call` is null and so there is nothing to clear.

Comment: Looks like a typo, I recommend tools like JSLint and others in order in order to find these sort of bugs ahead of time. Make sure you're familiar with the Chrome devtools too as they're pretty fast to point these things out :)

Comment: I'm voting to close as a typo since as a question it is unlikely to help future viewers of the site. Note that this doesn't reflect on you or your answer - only its usefulness to future readers.

Comment: No in my actual code the function was Start itself, not start. Made a typo over here

Comment: Actually I got my code working applying the logic from all the comments, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a case-sensitive language. This means that language keywords, variables, function names, and any other identifiers must always be typed with a consistent capitalization of letters. The while keyword, for your example, must be typed "Start", not "start" `var callback;
    var call=window.setInterval(callback,3000);

```
function Start(){//prompts,does validation and then setsinterval as so
      (function(){
        callback=function(){
      //declares numbers
          var Number = prompt("user enters a number between 1 to 9.", "0");

    };
    callback();
    window.setInterval(callback,3000);
  })();
    }
```

function Stop(){
      clearInterval(call);
    }`

Comment: Actually, that was a mistake I made in my example code. My actual code has start as Start only and its still not working

Comment: Yes that is correct. But I can not do it such because I want to set an interval for part of the Start function, not for the entire thing. I want to generate random numbers every 3 seconds, and this function is stored in the callback variable in the Start function and I declare it in the beginning to make it global.